# XML Namespace Conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I'm having issues with XML Namespace Conflict error as below.

Types 'XXXXXXX' and 'XXXXXXX' both use the XML type name, 'Customer', from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

I have an assembly with a 'Customer' class that is being used on 2 web services. The first web service is also calling the second web service. The conflict is happening on the 1st web service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting unique namespace on the 2 web services?

Comment: I have tried setting the namespace using the XMLRoot attribute: [XmlRoot(Namespace = "MyNamespace")]. I was wondering if there's a better way to do this.